# How to add tax to shipping Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

Hi I'm using Table Rates shipping method. Is there a way that the Shipping fee will have a tax as well, right now tax calculation is based only on cart sub total. Is there a way that the shipping fee has a tax as well.

Thank you,
JM

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to STORES > Settings > Configuration then expand the SALES panel and select Tax & expand the Tax Classes panel.

[image]

ps: or you can just customize a "Total Tax" for more clear info.

Comment: Forgot to add that there are different Tax computation on different country. So be sure to add it if your project is International.

Comment: Issue still exist.

Comment: @JmCabugnason Any further explanation about your problem?